# Ubuntu Mate on Macbook - Flickering Screen

Tags: boot, macbook, mate

So I installed Ubuntu Mate 15.10 on my 2014 13" Macbook Pro with Retina as a single boot. I wiped OSX off of my Macbook but kept the recovery partition just in case. For the first two hours it was working fine as I was doing updates and upgrades and installing the programs I needed (Wine, Steam). Then there started to be white pixels flashing all over the screen kind of like snow. I'm not sure when they started because they were hard to see until I opened up Steam. Then the screen started tearing so I rebooted the computer but it was still happening. So I did a full shutdown and needed to wait to try again because I was in class. After class the display wouldn't turn on at all and I needed to connect to an external display to recover my computer back to OSX to get the display working again. I thought it was a driver issue but the display should have not worked from the beginning. Any ideas what I might have done wrong?